# Is there a way to get all the attributes passed to an Ember component?

Tags: ember.js

For example, given the following code:

```
{{my-component foo="bar" baz="qux"}}
```

Inside the `my-component/component.js` file, I need a method to get all the passed attributes, something like this:

```
{
    foo: "bar",
    baz: "qux"
}
```

Does Ember have something to accomplish this? Or the only way is to do something hacky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best way to do is to do `Object.keys(this.attrs).map(k => this[k])` (Ember `3.1+`). Or `Object.keys(this.attrs).map(k => this.get(k))` (all Ember versions).

Dont use `this.attrs` directly. The values are wrapped in a quite weired way and it will probably be removed from ember soon-ish. Have a look at [this](https://locks.svbtle.com/to-attrs-or-not-to-attrs). For templates the `{{@arg}}` is added to ember. For js code we will probably get something like `this.args` at some point in the future. For now I would always access the argument on `this` directly, however I think using `Object.keys(this.attrs)` to get the names of all arguments passed to the component is fine.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can get the properties that are passed into a component.  Simply call `this.get('attrs')` within the component and you'll get an object of the passed in properties.

You won't have access to the attrs from within the template, so you'll need to create a computed property that returns the data you need. 
If your rely heavily on the list of attrs passed in, you'll want to hook into either didReceiveAttrs or didUpdateAttrs and notify the computed property that it should update.